# C Compilation error: request for member ___ in something not a structure or union

Tags: c, list, compiler-errors, linked-list, hashtable

I'm currently trying to create a hash table of strings. However in my search function I've been running into an error: request for member *_* in something not a structure or union.. again

```
 /*search hash table*/
    ListC search(hash_ref h, char* key){
        ListC* tempList;
        int hashvalue= hashing(h, key);
46      for(tempList= h->List[hashvalue]; tempList!=NULL; tempList=tempList->next){
47          if(strcmp(tempList->key,key)==0){
                return tempList;
            }
        }
        return NULL;
    }

    /*hash function*/
    int hashing(hash_ref h, char* key){
        int hashvalue=0;
        for(hashvalue=0;key!='\0';key++){
            hashvalue= *key + (hashvalue*5) - hashvalue;
        }
        return hashvalue%h->size;
    }

    /*HashTable struct*/
    typedef struct HashTable{
    int size;
    ListC **List;   
    }hash;

    typedef struct Node{
        long key;/*book id*/
        long count;
        struct Node* next;
        struct Node* prev;
    }NodeType;

    typedef NodeType* NodeRef;

    typedef struct ListCount{
        NodeRef first;
        NodeRef last;
        NodeRef current;
        long length;
    }ListCount;
```

ListC is defined in my header file as

```
typedef struct ListCount* ListC;
```

At lines 46 and 47 I get an error saying that key and next are the members that are not a structure. I'm not sure what's the problem here

Comment: What is the defintion of `listC`?

Comment: How you struct ListC is defined?

Comment: You `tempList` is of type `pointer to ListC`, but you haven't shown how `ListC` is defined. Right now, your `Node` type is the only one that seems to define a `next` field.

Comment: Woops sorry! I just edited my original post. But ListC is defined in my header file

Answer (score 2):

```
typedef struct ListCount* ListC;
```

So `ListC` is a pointer type.

```
ListC* tempList;
```

`tempList` is a pointer to a pointer to a `ListCount`.

```
... tempList=tempList->next ...
```

`tempList` does not point to a structure that has a member named `next`.

I suggest that this illustrates why defining a `typedef` for a pointer type is usually a bad idea. You have to keep track of levels of indirection anyway; it's typically easier to do so if all pointer types are explicit.

Comment: What is an easier solution to the problem then?

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct ListCount *ListC;
```

This line may not have been what you meant.

- `ListC` == `struct ListCount *`
- `ListC *` == `struct ListCount **`

```
ListC *foo = whatever;
foo->next;
```

is equivalent to

```
struct ListCount *foo = *whatever;
foo.next;
```

which of course is incorrect.

Try not to define pointer typedefs that don't make it obvious that they're pointer typedefs. For instance, you could `typedef struct ListCount *ListCPtr` if you really needed to; or just `typedef struct ListCount ListC`, which is what I think you wanted.

Comment: The thing is if I changed it to typedef struct ListCount ListC and still produces the same error. I even changed my ListC** List in my hash struct to ListC* List and still produces the same error

Answer (score 0):

ListC is a pointer point to a pointer which directly point to the struct Listcount.so，*LiatC dont't have the member next or key.
Check your typedef defination.